# Update method in Laravel does not update the record

Tags: laravel

I need to **update** database record. First of all I find the record by its primary key, then I filter items in request and finally call upadate method. Well, nothing happens.

**Controller**

```
$rec = \App\Contact::findOrFail($id);
$rec->update($request->only('first','last','city','region','zip'));
```

Plain **$request** value looks like this:

```
   {
        "_token": "myeF9lZOQBB8oH4h1ogUoZe4aEeEPxCw49J4qFtU",
        "_method": "PATCH",
        "first": "asdf",
        "last": "egsrsdeeee",
        "city": "erg",
        "region": "wfd",
        "zip": "23443",
        "phones": [
            "25313",
            "25313234",
            "25313234",
            "2531323523"
        ],
        "emails": [
            "jid@se.cz"
        ],
        "addresses": [
            "Petrovka 123",
            "dalsi vole 12"
        ]
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Seems it should work.

Comment: do you have this on your model? `protected $fillable = ['first','last','city','region','zip'];`

Answer (score 0):

Can we take a look at your model? Invoking `$request->only()` returns the values of the requests in array format, you'll have to make sure the indices of these values are in the `$fillables` property of your model.

And also are you sure that the update method is returning true? Can you show the output if you dump it:

```
$array = $request->only('first','last','city','region','zip');
\var_dump($rec->update($array));
```

And lastly, you could also just invoke `$request->toArray()`:

```
$rec->update($request->toArray());
```

since your model already knows what it should be filling as indicated with the `$fillable` property, with this you are also taking away the responsibility of knowing what indices you should manage in this particular class, and just letting the model do their task.

Answer (score 0):

On the model `Contact.php` add the following to the top:

```
protected $fillable = [
     'first',
     'last',
     'city',
     'region',
     'zip',
];
```

This will allow you to mass assign those fields only.